# Magento2 addFieldToFilter, Need 'and' and 'Or' in sql

Tags: magento2, collection, sql, customer-collection

I need magento sql collection.
Query need like that.
select * from custom_table where customer_id=xx or (customer_group=1 and custom_field=1)

I can add or operator like below 
select * from custom_table where customer_id=xx or (customer_group=1)
But needs to and operator with second OR.

My Current collection:

```
   $collection = $this->customTableFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(
       ['customer_id','custom_field'],
   [
       ['eq' =>$customerId],
       ['eq' =>1]
   ]);
```

Query From above collection: 
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `custom_table` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`customer_id` = 'xx') OR (`custom_field` = 1))

But I want collection like as below: Need to add And condition in second OR
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `custom_table` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`customer_id` = 'xx') OR (`custom_field` = 1 and `customer_group`=1))

Please help me if anyone get solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can do it as follows

$collection = $this->customTableFactory->create()->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->where("customer_group = '1' AND custom_field = '1'")->orWhere("customer_id='xx'");

Answer (score 0):

You can add your combined condition using the `where` function of the collection's select object. Something like this should work for you

```
$collection = $this->customTableFactory->create()->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId);
$collection->getSelect()->where('custom_field = 1 AND customer_group = 1');
```

Comment: Query Returning:  SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `shipping_account` AS `main_table` WHERE (`customer_id` = '27') AND (share_account = 1 AND customer_group = '1'). Dont need And operator between. Need Or. Posted answer on Query. Thanks!